# C# - How to close created form window from other form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm making a function in Form1 that make a new form.

```
private void makeForm(String option) {

        Form formWin = new Form();
        formWin.TopMost = true;
        formWin.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        formWin.Size = new Size(500,600);
        formWin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        formWin.Location = new Point(1366 - formWin.Size.Width , 768 - formWin.Size.Width);
        formWin.BackColor = Color.White;
        formWin.TransparencyKey = Color.White;

        var formWinModel = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "formWin",
            Size = new Size(formWin.Size.Width, formWin.Size.Height),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Image = Trans.Properties.Resources.Form_Special,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
        };

        formWin.Controls.Add(formWinModel);

        if (option == "show")
        {
            formWin.Show();
        }

        if (option == "exit") {
            formWin.Visible = false;
            formWin.Close();
            formWin.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When I used makeForm("show") it will create formWin form. But how to close formWin form. I used makeForm("exit") but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
private Form formWin = null;
private void makeForm(String option)
{
    if(formWin == null)
    {
        formWin = new Form();
        formWin.TopMost = true;
        formWin.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        formWin.Size = new Size(500, 600);
        formWin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        formWin.Location = new Point(1366 - formWin.Size.Width, 768 - formWin.Size.Width);
        formWin.BackColor = Color.White;
        formWin.TransparencyKey = Color.White;

        var formWinModel = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "formWin",
            Size = new Size(formWin.Size.Width, formWin.Size.Height),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Image = Trans.Properties.Resources.Form_Special,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
        };

        formWin.Controls.Add(formWinModel);
    }            

    if (option == "show")
    {
        formWin.Show();
    }

    if (option == "exit")
    {
        formWin.Visible = false;
        formWin.Close();
        formWin.Dispose();
        formWin = null;
    }
}
```

You should create formWin varibale in out makeForm function. I hope it help you.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer suggests, how does yours improve that?

Comment: You call makeForm("show") function, formWin  will be created. If you want close formWin, you call makeForm("exit").

Comment: Thanks @TienNguyen. Work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You have created a *Modal* window, which means the previous form, (the one that you opened `formWin` from) wont be accessible while `formWin` is active. If you want both forms to be accessible at the same time, you should use `formWin.Show()` instead.

Your method wont work anyways because you're looking for a local variable (form) to close which is not possible, you should declare `Form formWin` outside of your method and save the value to this variable. When you later want to close it. But that's gonna cause some other problems such as what if you wanted to create multiple forms at the same time? Which questions your whole logic, why even close the Form from your previous Form?

Comment: Thanks, Already changes formWin.ShowDialog() to formWin.Show().But how to close formWin form from my previous form ? Because my formWin FormBorderStyle is set to None. @Deadzone

Comment: @DovahkiiND I added some more info in the answer.